# VS 2012 not opening .cs file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mightymoose

I recently installed [Mighty Moose(Continuous Tests)](http://continuoustests.com/) and ever since it seems to have stopped from being able to open .cs files in VS. I've uninstalled MM but I am still having this issue.

I've also resent my settings in VS with no luck.

Any suggestions?

[image: VS No code showing]

Comment: Sadly, I've got exactly the same issue. Wish I'd never installed this add-in.

Comment: If it helps, I reinstalled VS SP2 and it worked fine. Not the preferred option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything for this so just reinstalled the SP and it seemed to work.